# TFS: Link commit to work item stop working (entire collection)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I've been using the automatic links between commits and WI in TFS by writing #id in the commit message.
However, it stopped working for the entire collection, not only for a single project.
All the projects have checked the "Automatically create links for work items mentioned in a commit comment."
I´m really lost and I don´t know how to fix it.
Thank you very much for your ideas and support.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below suggestions. How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the work item exists and you have the permission to view this work item (you can see it on your project portal) when you tried to link it to a commit.

When you make a commit on your local repo. You need to push your commit to the tfs server.

This option `Automatically create links for work items mentioned in a commit comment.` is set on repository level. You can check if the this option is checked for the repositories.

If above are all good, you can try unchecking the option `Automatically create links for work items mentioned in a commit comment`  and save, then check this option and save again.

Comment: I've tried that but the problem is still happening.